# Oraclize Sample contracts failing in JavaScript VM: VM Exception: out of gas / invalid opcode

Tags: remix, oracles, javascript-vm

I'm simply trying to run one of the sample contracts [here at dapps.oraclize.it/browser-solidity/](http://dapps.oraclize.it/browser-solidity/#gist=9817193e5b05206847ed1fcd1d16bd1d) e.g. DieselPrice.sol.

When I create the contract without passing a value I get `VM Exception: out of gas` and when I do pass a value I get `VM Exception: invalid opcode`.

I'm wondering what's happening here.. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the issue by changing the solidity version of the compiler to 0.4.20, making the constructor payable and removing calling 'update()' from the constructor.

[This Github issue](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/issues/21) may provide some more info.